# Problem with script to change number of Flatlist columns depending on rotation/size

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm working on some code to calculate numColumns for a flatlist- intention is 3 on landscape tablet, 2 on portrait tablet, and 1 on portrait phone.

Here's my code:

```
const [width, setWidth] = useState(Dimensions.get('window').width);
const [imageWidth, setImageWidth] = useState(100);
const [imageHeight, setImageHeight] = useState(100);

const [columns, setColumns] = useState(3);

useEffect(() => {
    function handleChange() {
        setWidth(Dimensions.get('window').width);
    }
    Dimensions.addEventListener("change", handleChange);
    return () => Dimensions.removeEventListener("change", handleChange);
}, [width]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (width > 1100) {
        setColumns(3);
    } else if (width <= 1099 && width > 600) {
        setColumns(2);
    } else {
        setColumns(1);
    }
    setImageWidth((width - (64 * columns) + 15) / columns);
    setImageHeight(((width - (64 * columns) + 15) / columns) * .6);
}, [width]);
```

imageWidth and imageHeight are passed to the render component of the flatlist to size an image.

It seems to work fine when I load it in landscape mode, but if I rotate to portrait, I get this:

[image]

Then, if I go back to landscape, it stays as 2 columns?

[image]

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning the height of the device, afterwards, you need to calculate the orientation of the device (`isLandscape`).

Logically it flows as the following:

1. is the device landscape? (setColumns 3)
2. is the device wide and portrait? (set columns 2)
3. others (setColumns 1)

From there you can pass that into the second useEffect, (say, `useColumnsHook`). This should be able to set the height/width based on orientation of the device.

I also recommend setting the height/width based on percentages rather than exact pixels for devices (`100%, 50%, 33.3%`).

```js
const [width, setWidth] = useState(Dimensions.get('window').width);
const [imageWidth, setImageWidth] = useState(100);
const [imageHeight, setImageHeight] = useState(100);

const [columns, setColumns] = useState(3);

/**
 * orientation
 * 
 * return {
 *   width,
 *   height
 * }
 */
const useScreenData = () => {
  const [screenData, setScreenData] = useState(Dimensions.get("screen"))

  useEffect(() => {
    const onChange = (result) => {
      setScreenData(result.screen)
    }

    Dimensions.addEventListener("change", onChange)

    return () => Dimensions.removeEventListener("change", onChange)
  })

  return {
    ...screenData,
  }
}

const { width, height } = useScreenData()
const isLandscape = width > height


useEffect(() => {
  if (isLandscape && width > 1100) {
    // handle landscape
    setColumns(3)
  } else if (!isLandscape && (width <= 1099 && width > 600)) {
    setColumns(2)
  } else {
    setColumns(1)
  }

  setImageWidth((width - (64 * columns) + 15) / columns);
  setImageHeight(((width - (64 * columns) + 15) / columns) * .6);
}, [width, isLandscape]);
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me fix it. Device orientation is unneccessary though, at the end of the day I only care about device width. Sorry if that wasn't clear in my question.

Answer (score 0):

**1:Tablet or Phone**

You can use the [react-native-device-info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-device-info) package along with the Dimensions API. Check the `isTablet()` method and apply different styles according on the result.

if you care Expo user then you have to user expo-constants  `userInterfaceIdiom` method to detect isTablet [Reference](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/constants/)

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';

let isTablet = DeviceInfo.isTablet();
```

**2:Portrait mode or Landscape mode**

then you can find portrait mode or landscape mode by

```
const isPortrait = () => {
    const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
    return dim.height >= dim.width;
};
```

**3:Code:**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, Text, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import DeviceInfo from "react-native-device-info";

const App = () => {
  const isLandscapeFunction = () => {
    const dim = Dimensions.get("screen");
    return dim.width >= dim.height;
  };

  const [width, setWidth] = useState(Dimensions.get("window").width);
  const [imageWidth, setImageWidth] = useState(100);
  const [imageHeight, setImageHeight] = useState(100);

  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(3);

  let isTabletPhone = DeviceInfo.isTablet();;
  useEffect(() => {
    function handleChange(result) {
      setWidth(result.screen.width);
      const isLandscape = isLandscapeFunction();
      if (isLandscape && isTabletPhone) {
        setColumns(3);
      } else if (!isLandscape && isTabletPhone) {
        setColumns(2);
      } else {
        setColumns(1);
      }
    }
    Dimensions.addEventListener("change", handleChange);
    return () => Dimensions.removeEventListener("change", handleChange);
  });


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(columns);
    setImageWidth((width - 64 * columns + 15) / columns);
    setImageHeight(((width - 64 * columns + 15) / columns) * 0.6);
  }, [columns, width]);

  return (
    <View style={{ justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", flex: 1 }}>
      <Text>imageWidth {imageWidth}</Text>
      <Text>imageHeight {imageHeight}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```